# How to find Intel SKU for Mac CPUs

Tags: mac, cpu, macos

Seems like everywhere you can go to purchase a laptop they specify the Intel SKU for each CPU option - except Apple.  If you *have* a Mac, you can apparently find this info using the following command:

```
sysctl -n machdep.cpu.brand_string
```

For instance, on my Mac, this returns:

```
Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3330S CPU @ 2.70GHz
```

The number I am interested in here is the "i5-3330S", the Intel SKU.

However, if I don't own a Mac, how can I find this info?  It doesn't seem to be anywhere on Apple's web site, even in the tech specs.  For instance, Apple just announced a new 2015 MacBook, and a refresh to the 13" MacBook Pro lines.  Where/how can I find what CPUs are actually in these products?

Update: It appears that Wikipedia now lists the Intel SKUs for the latest (2015) Macs. For instance, from the [MacBook Air](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacBook_Air) page it shows the latest Air (sic) model uses an i5-5250U with an optional i7-5650U.  However, [footnote 55](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacBook_Air#cite_note-Early_2015-56) cites a [Apple's own specs page](http://www.apple.com/macbook-air/specs.html) which not only contain no SKUs as far as I can see, but aren't even for the new 12" model!  So where is this info coming from?

Comment: here is a almost up to date list http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Macintosh_models_grouped_by_CPU_type#Overview

Comment: @Buscar웃 The site you linked doesn't contain the actual model string. For example, my Air shows `Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4650U CPU @ 1.70GHz`, but the site only shows "Processor: Core i7 ULT (2-core), Model: MacBook Air, Clock speed (in GHz): 1.7, L2 cache: 2×256, L3 cache: 4, L4 cache: —, CPUs: 1, Cores per CPU: 2, HT: Yes, ITB: Yes, Introduced: June 2013, Discontinued: current". The fact that the processor is a i7-4650U is missing.

Comment: http://www.everymac.com - though presumably it'll take them a while to get the latest machines on there - you can even search by the SKU number